# How to insert multiple IDs into a sql statement?

Tags: python, pandas

New to python and pandas, Im facing the following issue:

I would like to pass multiple string into a sql query and struggle to insert the delimiter ',' :

```
Example data

import pandas as pd

data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
print (df)

# Remove header (Not sure whether that is necessary)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]


pd.read_sql(

    """
SELECT
*

FROM emptable
WHERE empID IN ('{}',)

    """.format(df.ix[:, 0]), # Which corresponds to 'Alex','Bob','Clarke'

    con = connection)
```

I tried different combinations, however None of them have worked out.

Answer (score 2):

Demo:

```
sql_ = """
SELECT *
FROM emptable
WHERE empID IN ({})
"""

sql = sql_.format(','.join([x for x in ['?'] * len(df)]))
print(sql)

new = pd.read_sql(query, conn, params=tuple(df['Name']))
```

Output:

```
In [166]: print(sql)

SELECT *
FROM emptable
WHERE empID IN (?,?,?)
```

NOTE: this approach will not work if your DF is large, because the generated SQL string would be too big.

In this case you can save/dump Names in a helper temporary table and use it in SQL:

```
df[['Name']].to_sql('tmp', conn, if_exists='replace')

sql = """
SELECT *
FROM emptable
WHERE empID IN (select Name from tmp)
"""
new = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.  How can you make sure that `'Alex','Bob','Clarke'` is passed as strings. Right know your code doesnt include any explicit quotes. At least thats the syntax for mysql if passing a string.

Comment: @Mamba, you don't have to - it'll be done for you automatically